# Why is declaring an array using so much CPU, and how can I optimize it?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, netbeans, profiling

I am writing a chess engine as a learning project. To decide what move to make, it needs to analyze all board states that can be reached by making 4 moves from the current board state. That means I have to analyze hundreds of thousands of boards.

The code is understandably slow, so I used the built in Netbeans profiler to see which function I should optimize. I was surprised to find that it was simply the creation of new arrays within copied `Board` objects that was using the most CPU.

Here is the function that it says is using the most CPU, specifically `init1()`:

```
private void initializeFields(Color active) {
    init1();
    init2(active);
    init3();
    init4();
}

private void init1() {
    //this line appears to be using a ton of CPU
    pieces = new Piece[SQUARES_PER_SIDE][SQUARES_PER_SIDE];
}

private void init2(Color active) {
    activePlayer = active;
}

private void init3() {
    moveHistory = new LinkedList<>();
}

private void init4() {
    possibleMoves = null;
}
```

And here are the profiler results:

[image]

Obviously I understand that the vast amount of boards being created and looked at means that some small thing within the `Board` class is probably going to take the most CPU. However, I have 2 questions about this:

**1. Why is declaration of an array taking the most CPU of anything withing `Board`?**

I was expecting move calculation or analysis of the value of each board state to use more than simply creating arrays. Is it possible I am reading the results incorrectly?

**2. How can I optimize my performance in this case?**

I understand how to optimize algorithms, but I am not sure how to optimize an array declaration. I am also not sure what better data structure I can use to represent an 8x8 board than a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Unfortunately you cut off the column that shows how _often_ that method is called. Is that the time for a single call or many calls? If many, then how many?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't cut anything off... that column isn't there for me. Let me see if I can try to get it to show up. However, it is almost certainly for many calls since we know hundreds of thousands of boards will be initialized during profiling

Comment: Click in the upper right corner of the result table, there you can select which columns to display: http://imgur.com/a/QsRLD

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name checked on this, it is 3000 calls even for a fairly short run of the program.

Comment: So it's about 12ms per call that does seem rather slow. How big is that array? Short of creating a smaller array, you can probably only improve that if you call the function less frequently.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's just a chess board so 8x8. I am looking into using only a single board and making then undoing moves based on that, but any other suggestions are appreciated since that requires a large scale rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is declaration of an array taking the most CPU of anything withing Board?

Because that is propbably almost all you do. Searching for free space in the heap is taking up more time than anything else.

> 2. How can I optimize my performance in this case?

Keep just one board and make each move, test it and undo the move for each step.

This is a bad approach if you ever want to parallelise but it is much quicker and more space-efficient. (good call @shmosel)

Comment: @shmosel Nothing stops you from creating 16 boards, or 96 or whatever the amount of cores you have at your disposal.

Comment: @Kayaman That would lock each branch to a specific thread, meaning you lose the opportunity for work stealing.

Comment: This is a good idea, and I am looking into it. If implementing it improves my performance significantly and doesn't cause other issues, I will accept the answer. In the meantime I will leave this open in case anyone else has different optimization ideas

Comment: This exposed some other issues that I had to fix, but at the end of the day it improved performance by 20x or more. Thanks!